# JQuery filter DataTable rows by row tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable where each row have a tag.

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr mytag = "tag1">
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr mytag = "tag2">
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Have a select box with all the tags.

```
<select id="select_tag" class="select2-original">           
    <option value="tag1">tag1</option>
    <option value="tag2">tag2</option>              
</select>
```

And when a tag is selected, I want to filter the table and only display the rows with the tag but what I did is not working.

```
var mytable= $('#mytable').DataTable();
$('#select_tag').on('change', function () {
  var tagvalue = this.value;
  mytable
    .rows(function (idx, data, node) {
        return node.getAttribute("mytag") == tagvalue? true : false;
     })
    .draw();
})
```

Have also tried .hide(), add .data()... nothing works so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
  <div class="form-control">
    <label>Filter</label>
    <select id="select_tag" class="form-control select2-original">           
    <option value="tag1">tag1</option>
    <option value="tag2">tag2</option>              
</select>
  </div>
  </div>


</div>

<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-mytag = "tag1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Ram</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-mytag = "tag2">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Shiva</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-mytag = "tag2">
              <td>3</td>
              <td>Vishnu</td>
         </tr>
        <tr data-mytag = "tag1">
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Sita</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var mytable= $('#mytable').DataTable();
$('#select_tag').on('change', function () {
  mytable.draw();
});

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
     function( settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter ) {
       var row = mytable.row(index).node();
       var filterValue = $(row).data('mytag');
       var e = document.getElementById("select_tag");
       var filter = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
       if(filterValue == filter)
          return true;

     }
);
```

[CODEPEN Link](https://codepen.io/gireeshcse/pen/KKVKJdb)

[More Info on Search Extension](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search)

Comment: This is great! Thanks!